# Installing VS.net '08 on Vista Home

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-vista

I have a problem that makes me tear every hair on my head for the past 2 days. I finally decided to give my laptop, dinosaurs running on XP to my mother, to join my wife's computer, runing under Vista. But I am facing a hard reality, I never work on Vista and now I must install my Visual Studio 2008 and I confess that I am about to fall into depression. The installation always falls into error during installation with an error message:

> There were errors during setup.
>   Although the components were installed
>   successfully, some setup errors were
>   detected

The problem is that it simply have time to install anything. There has never been the slightest trace of a Visual Studio on this machine, I do not see why it's not installing. I've looked for installed programs if there's any Visual Studio trace or framework and see that there's .net Framework 3.5 and decided to removed it.

After what i've tried to re-install it. It succesfully install .net Framework 3,5 after it falls again for the same reason.

So if anyone has succeeded by I don't know which miracle to install Visual Studio 2008 under Vista Home without reformatting or without shooting the computer by the window and regretted having given his laptop to his mother, please write here how to do!

Thanks, and I love you mom :P

Comment: probably superuser.com question

Comment: I am running VS 2008 Team Systems, over windows Vista home premium.
No problems so far

Comment: It's also an VS 2008 Team Systems ...

Comment: well still now able to install it !! ... should I install express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems initially, but got them fixed. Honetly it's a hell if you get into it. Following post were quiet helpful

http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2007/11/22/visual-studio-2008-install-problems-and-solutions.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/ecb1403a-a343-43d9-92c6-a50f5bee3cf6/

http://grumpywookie.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/problems-installing-visual-studio-2008-on-vista-x64/

Hope it helps

Comment: I will try to follow your links tomorow. Thanks you!

Comment: I cannot remember exactly what was the problem (8 months) but I think, It was something to do with .Net framework / service packs. Some order was required to install them. I not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run the installer as administrator.  Just being logged into the administrator account isn't enough.  You must still right-click on the installer and use the "Run as administrator" option.

Comment: Oups, it something i've forgetten to write, i've tried this option!